# Deserialization exception while POSTing nested json to Spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring, following is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/campaigns/addTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Campaign addTaskToCampaign(@RequestParam(value = "campaignName")String campaignName,@Valid @RequestBody Task task) {
  Campaign campaign = campaignInterface.findByName(campaignName);
  if (campaign!=null){
    List<String> task_ids;
    if (campaign.getTask_ids()==null){
      task_ids = new ArrayList<>();
    }else{
      task_ids= campaign.getTask_ids();
    }
    Task newTask = taskInterface.save(task);
    task_ids.add(newTask.getId());
    campaign.setTask_ids(task_ids);
    return campaignInterface.save(campaign);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Where my task model is:

```
@Document(collection = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    private int points;

    private List<Question>questions;

    private List<String>answers;

    ...
}
```

And the nested question model is:

```
public class Question {
    private Boolean isText = false;
    private String questionText;
}
```

But, the same model when POSTing as nested json throws an HTTP 400 exception saying json unreadable exception, and it tried to parse the String questionText field as a boolean value.

Here is what im POSTing:

```
{
  "name" : "Test Task 3",
  "questions": [{ "questionText":"What is the name you college festival?","isText":true}]
}
```

And the exception that comes is this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1497508476467,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize value of type boolean from String \"What is the name you college festival?\": only \"true\" or \"false\" recognized; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type boolean from String \"What is the name you college festival?\": only \"true\" or \"false\" recognized\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6a371c03; line: 3, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.frapp.CBM.prod.model.Task[\"questions\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.frapp.CBM.prod.model.Question[\"questionText\"])",
  "path": "/campaigns/addTask"
}
```

Any help is appreciated. ive been trying for hours. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: do you try rebuild?

Comment: yes. i did a rebuild from the build menu. i also did gradle run twice.

Comment: From the parsing error it seems it is expecting Boolean value for questionText. Please check the data type of questionText in server code.

Comment: I feel like your `questionText` setter argument is of type `Boolean` (copy-paste error?)

Comment: I am assuming that your class questions has getters and setters? If so please can you add them to your code.

Comment: the server has the type defined as String and ive pasted the error message. Also since im usign intelliJ the getter setters are auto generated and they are of the same type as the variable type.

Comment: did that, check the requestBody in the code, questionText comes first, tried switching that too

Comment: The first comment I would make to any of my developers is: please can you rename your boolean.

This is because the getter will look like: `isIsText()`.

As a general rule it is good practice to avoid starting a field name with "get", "set", or "is".

Comment: @MartinByers Thank you very much! that was indeed the issue. the getter setter names were messed up. due to which the text and isText generated the same getter as getText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment I would make to any of my developers is: please can you rename your `boolean`. This is because the getter will look like: `isIsText()`.

As a general rule it is good practice to avoid starting a field name with "get", "set", or "is".

This is because these are the prefixes of java-beans properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/campaigns/addTask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Campaign addTaskToCampaign(@RequestParam Map<String,Object> campaignName,@Valid @RequestBody Task task){

     /* 
      if there is exception then just remove Task put it into json to catch into map.        
      access just as map by campaignName.get("key_name");
     */

        Campaign campaign = campaignInterface.findByName(campaignName);
        if (campaign!=null){
            List<String> task_ids;
            if (campaign.getTask_ids()==null){
                task_ids = new ArrayList<>();
            }else{
                task_ids= campaign.getTask_ids();
            }
            Task newTask = taskInterface.save(task);
            task_ids.add(newTask.getId());
            campaign.setTask_ids(task_ids);
            return campaignInterface.save(campaign);
        }
        return null;
    }
```